# Update using Substr in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, substring

I need to change the first four digits in a field. Here is my sql:

```
update [SRT-HR-DW].[dbo].[FACT_PAYROLL]
```

set substr(EMPLOYEE_ID,1,5) = 'E1304'
where substr(EMPLOYEE_ID,1,5) like 'E1302%';

can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What did you expect to see? What did you really see?

Answer (score 0):

More like

```
update [SRT-HR-DW].[dbo].[FACT_PAYROLL]
set employee_id = replace(employee_id, 'E1302', 'E1304'  ) 
where employee_id like 'E1302%';
```

or if E1302 can appear more than once in the employee_id something like

```
update [SRT-HR-DW].[dbo].[FACT_PAYROLL]
set employee_id =  'E1304' + right(employee_id,len(employee_id)-5) 
where employee_id like 'E1302%';
```